# How can I give Sinatra a catchall, default route?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

For a small developer documentation app, I'd like to set up a Sinatra app to just serve HAML files. After routes for CSS files and images, I want a route that tries to load a HAML file for any path you request.

For example:

- `/index` loads `views/index.haml`, if it exists
- `/this/page/might/exist` loads `views/this/page/might/exist.haml`, if it exists

How would I specify this route?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looks like this will do it:

```
get '/*' do
  viewname = params[:splat].first   # eg "some/path/here"

  if File.exist?("views/#{viewname}.haml")
    haml :"#{viewname}"

  else
    "Nopers, I can't find it."
  end
end
```

Comment: I had to put this 'after' all my other routes, to make sure they get processed, otherwise the catchall route `/*` would block all the other routes

Comment: @nroose - a 500 error is something a web server would return; it can't happen in Ruby. If, eg, the `haml` call raises an error, you're right that I wouldn't rescue it and my site would return a 500. Also, to be more correct, I should send a 404 status code in the header when sending the body "I can't find it". But this is just a simple example.

Comment: Just wanted to note that this _does_ cover `/` (the root route)